# Google Plus credentials for application Login

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plus

I am creating an app and I want to confirm user using the Google credentials in Java environment. It can be done using google API but I am not sure how to code it as a servlet.

I found a code snippet to authorize the credentials but the AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp() is throwing an error and I am not sure which api to use.

```
private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    // load client secrets
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,
        new InputStreamReader(Test.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json")));
    if (clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientId().startsWith("Enter")
        || clientSecrets.getDetails().getClientSecret().startsWith("Enter ")) {
      System.out.println(
          "Enter Client ID and Secret from https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=plus "
          + "into plus-cmdline-sample/src/main/resources/client_secrets.json");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    // set up authorization code flow
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets,
        Collections.singleton(PlusScopes.PLUS_ME)).setDataStoreFactory(
        dataStoreFactory).build();
    // authorize
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
  }
```

Hope someone can help me with this and also let me know the process it'll be great...

Answer (score 2):

If you really are writing a servlet to run under Google AppEngine, it is much much easier than that.

```
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory;

...

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
  UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
  User currentUser = userService.getCurrentUser();
  if (currentUser == null) {
    resp.sendRedirect(userService.createLoginURL(req.getRequestURI()));
  }
  else {
    // show the view
  }
}
```

Comment: will this allow me to authenticate the user ??

Comment: how should the user be authenticated ??

Comment: How can I login to the system